# Mac osX boot camp issue

Tags: macos, mac, startup

i tried installing windows 8.1 on my mac osX and while the boot camp process was on the disk partitioning was in process and my mac suddenly restarted with a bootcamp error. now there is no windows8.1 installed on my mac but my storage shows partitioned please help

Answer (score 1):

1. Go into disk utility.
2. Select your hard drive or SSD.
3. Click partition at the top.
4. Click the '-' button, then click apply.
5. You might have to restart you computer, but then it shouldn't say that it is partitioned.

Try to install bootcamp again and it should work.